# why the google chrome css background images only show when the image span has content

Tags: html, css

I define a code block to show an icon in the source html page in google chrome extension like this:

```
<div id="translate-btn" style="">
        <button type="button" class="bp3-button">
          <span class="btn-icon">Translate</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

when the user click the words on the original web page, show the icon. I changed the div visible or hidden in the javascript code. this is the css define:

```
#translate-btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999999999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

#translate-btn .bp3-button {
  padding: 2px;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

#translate-btn .btn-icon {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  background-image: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/resource/image/logo.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.bp3-dark #translate-btn .btn-icon {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  background-image: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/resource/image/logowhite36.png');
}

#translate-btn.show {
  display: block;
}
```

now I found the problem is that the span element added `Translate` words, the background image show with the words `Translate`, when did not add the `Translate` word, the background image did not show. why did this happen? what should I do to fix this problem to make the image always show no matter add the `Translate` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why no `background-image`

`span` is a generic *inline* container. In this case, it practically means that it'll collapse when there's no content inside. That is, `background-image` doesn't have any space to fill.

### How to address

Should you want the background image always visible without any content inside, you could consider:

- Adding it to the parent `button` element
- Using a block level container for `.btn-icon`

Also, You could reconsider the use of `background-image` altogether. Is it really a background? Why can't it be an `img` instead? Or perhaps a Base64 encoded inline content?